# HTML Formated data sending and handling from Angular JS to GoLang

Tags: angularjs, go

I'm trying to send the HTML formated data from angular-JS to Go Lang API server.
I'm Using Angular Trix and sending the HTML formated Data To API.

Here is My Angular-Js Service Class code....

```
sendblogData(data,key){
    console.log(angular.toJson(data))
    this.$http({
        url:"/api/BlogPost",
        method:"POST",
        data:{
            "blogData":angular.toJson(data),
            "blogId": key
        }
    }).then((response)=>{
        if(response.data.status === "success") {
            console.log("mission successfull......")
        }
    })

}
```

And Here Is my Go Lang Controller Code

```
func blogDetailsPost(c *gin.Context) {
  var request struct {
    ID          string `json:"blogId"`
    BlogDetails string `json:"blogData"`
  }

  if c.Bind(&request) == nil {
    fmt.Println("request", request.BlogDetails)
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
      "status":  "success",
      "message": "Mision successfull....",
    })
  }
}
```

But I'm getting 400 Bad Request Response.

Can Any One please suggest me where i make mistake.

Comment: What package is `gin`? Please give a link to it. Have you checked if you enter `blogDetailsPost`?

Comment: You need to look at the actual request body sent over the wire, to see if it conforms to your expectations. You should also check the Content-Type header.

Comment: its Gin Web Framework. Yes I mentioned blogDetailsPost.

Comment: @Flimzy 
1)actually i'm trying to send ng-model value of angular-Trix. so I just Converted data using angular.toJson() methode.and This ng-model containg the full user input in a HTML format.
2) And Except this Post all other post is working properly.